# Native Script ScrollView and AbsoluteLayout

Tags: scrollview, absolutelayout, nativescript

Im new to NS and I have a project. I want a Button floating inside a ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView>
     <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
           <AbsoluteLayout >
               <Button top="0" left="0" right="0" text="Test" style="font-size: 10; margin:5; " />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
                <Label text="Trending Now: " cssClass="trending-label" />
                <Repeater items="{{ categories }}">
                    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                </Repeater>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

But its not working. The Button is also scrolling. I want the Button to be floating on ScrollView. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the button is scrolling together with the other items is that everything is situated in a ScrollView. In order to have only the Label and the Repeater scrolling, the Button should be placed outside of it.

Another thing I have noticed is that on the Button, simultaneously are applied left and right alignment, which might cause a problem.

I made a possible implementation of the float button, which you can check [here](https://gist.github.com/N3ll/e3c087b056cfee2fd11f).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you suggested, it works, the button floats but the scrolling was not possible..

Comment: The scrolling depends on how many items you have inside the "categories" collection. You can try including more items, so they are exceed the screen size.

Comment: I tried adding more items but it still not scrolling :(

Comment: Can you give some more information about the device or emulator, you are testing on and the code, so I can try to simulate it.